# Validating JSON scheme using javascript + tv4

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I am trying to validate JSON scheme using [TV4](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/).

My validation is using hierarchical JSON and is based on this basic [example](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%09%22foo%22%3a%20%22bar%22%0A%7D&schema=%7B%0A%09%22type%22%3a%20%22object%22,%0A%09%22properties%22%3a%20%7B%0A%09%09%22foo%22%3a%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%22type%22%3a%20%22string%22%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D,%0A%09%22required%22%3a%20%5B%22foo%22%5D%0A%7D):

```
var data = {
    "foo": "bar"
};

var schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["foo"]
};

var result = tv4.validateResult(data, schema);
```

In my test I want to add one more hierarchy level:

```
 var data = {
        "foo": {
           "test": "bar"
        }
    };

    var schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "foo": {
                    "test": {
                       "type": "string"
                     }
            }
        },
        "required": ["foo"]
    };

    var result = tv4.validateResult(data, schema);
```

This validation does not work (if I put an integer instead of a string it passes the [validation](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22foo%22%3a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22test%22%3a%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&schema=%7B%0A%09%22type%22%3a%20%22object%22,%0A%09%22properties%22%3a%20%7B%0A%09%09%22foo%22%3a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22test%22%3a%7B%0A%09%09%09%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3a%20%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D,%0A%09%22required%22%3a%20%5B%22foo%22%5D%0A%7D))

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never used TV4 before.

I'd guess that the schema should specify the `foo` property as an `object` with a `string` property... Something like:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "foo": {
            "properties": {
                "test": {
                   "type": "string"
                 }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "required": ["foo"]
}
```

Comment: Tnx, I had figured it out by myself, but your answer is correct (accepting your answer)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at this [forum question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/json-schema/20-W2yq30po) I figured out that I am missing the "properties" attribute for the sub tree. Now it will [work](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22foo%22%3a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22test%22%3a%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&schema=%7B%0A%09%22type%22%3a%20%22object%22,%0A%09%22properties%22%3a%20%7B%0A%09%09%22foo%22%3a%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3a%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22test%22%3a%7B%0A%09%09%09%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3a%20%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D,%0A%09%22required%22%3a%20%5B%22foo%22%5D%0A%7D) (when the value is an integer it will fail the validation.